# Overwriting Buffer still leads to memory crash

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to convert an AVI video into a series of images, saving only the most recent eight seconds of video into the 'buffer'. I'm only saving two bits of information: the timestamp for when the image was pulled from the AVI, and the image itself.

My problem is that even though the program is written for the buffer to overwrite itself, it is still having memory crashes - about 2 minutes in, for an 8s buffer. (error: (-4) Failed to allocate ###### bytes in function cv::OutofMemoryError) The code for this thread is below the aside for context.

(Context: I'm trying to create an emulator for a frame grabber. It constantly/endlessly converts a saved AVI, and restarts itself when it reaches the end of the video. The buffer is supposed to be analogous to whatever hardware - an HDD or SSD or whatever- that the frame grabber is actually saving to, in practice. This emulator runs as its own thread, parallel to another thread that processes & sends images as they are requested. The crash occurs without invoking the second thread.)

```
import base64, os, cv2, re, time, math
from PIL import Image
from threading import Thread

lobal numbertosave, framearray, sessionlist
framearray = []
vidfile = os.path.normpath("videolocation")
savepath = os.path.normpath("whereIsaverequestedimages"

class FrameInfo:
    def __init__(self, frame, time):
        self.f = frame
        self.t = time

def VidEmulator():
    global numbertosave, framearray, hit, fps
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(vidfile)
    fps = video.get(5)
    ##### Change the integer in the expression below to the number of seconds you want ot save
    numbertosave = int(fps*5)
    ######## numbertosave = framerate * (# of seconds to store in buffer)
    totalframes = video.get(7)
    atframe = 1
    count = 1
    framearray = [0] * numbertosave
    deltat = []
    converting = True
    while converting == True:
        try:
            ret, frame = video.read()
            timestamp = time.time()
            x = FrameInfo(frame, timestamp)
            framearray[count] = ((x.f, x.t))
            atframe = atframe + 1
            count = count + 1
            if count == numbertosave:
                count = 1
                VidEmulator()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #### edited to remove mention of other thread, which isn't
            #### invoked when testing this one (it is on request; see
            #### comments) I honestly haven't tested this block since I
            #### usually ctrl+printbreak
            t1.join()
            print "threads killed"
            exit()
            print "hopefully you don't see this"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target = VidEmulator)
    t1.start()
```

I'm guessing there's probably a very simple logic problem I'm having here from preventing the buffer from actually overwriting itself, or some other variable is 'hanging', accumulating with consecutive runs and crashing the program. Otherwise, is there a better way to handle this problem, that will evade this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you recursively invoking `VidEmulator()`?!

Comment: Btw, I cannot see any `t2`, but `t1.join()` looks like a straight deadlock.

Comment: Yes, I am, when the max buffer size (fps*8) is reached, it sets the count to 1 and calls VidEmulator() again.

Comment: I left out t2 because it's not being invoked before the crash occurs. (to test, I was starting the program and leaving it to run. t1 runs continuously and t2 is on request, so it's effectively what I have here.) I'll remove t2 in an edit...

Comment: Then, because `VidEmulator()` basically never returns, you'll have an endless recursion running until (stack) memory is exhausted. Also, this way you do `video = cv2.VideoCapture(vidfile)` over and over again. Not sure if that's what you intend. Then, you also completely discard the buffer's content in `framearray = [0] * numbertosave` as soon as it has gathered `numbertosave` frames. - In short: Remove the recursion.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. thanks! if you post this as an answer and it works out, I'll accept it in a bit.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to resolve the recursion problem? I am having trouble coming up with a method that works....